# Convert string to date, add one day and then post as part of a query string

Tags: javascript

I have a <p> that currently holds 2015-02-02 (Todays Date). I want to take this string, add one to the date and then post it as part of a query string to an RPG program (part of the URL). With my current code, nothing is happening?

```
 <p id="result"><%= (Today) %></p>
 <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Next Day" onClick="nextDay()">
```

Javascipt

```
 function nextDay(){

    var currDate = document.getElementById('results').innerHTML ;
    var dt = new Date(currDate);
    dt = dt.setDate( gt.getDate + 1 )
    var newDate= = dt.toString();

    url = 'http://bvr:7018/CLPOOREa.rpgle?CurrDate=' + newDate; 
    window.location.href = url; 
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) will make your life much easier when working with dates.

Comment: It currently displays 2015-02-02

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextDay(){

    var currDate = document.getElementById('results').innerHTML ;
    var tomorrow = new Date(currDate);
    tomorrow = tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

    url = 'http://bvr:7018/CLPOOREa.rpgle?CurrDate=' + tomorrow; 
    window.location.href = url; 
}
```

This might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

setDate() does not return a date, it sets the day of that Date instance. As mentioned, please have a look at Moment.js. But this should help too:

```
var today = new Date();
console.log('Today is : ' + today);
var tomorrowDay = today.getDate() + 1;
console.log('Tomorrow\'s day number is: ' + tomorrowDay);
today.setDate(tomorrowDay);
console.log('Tomorrow is: ' + today.toString());

//output
"Today is : Mon Feb 02 2015 08:18:06 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" 
"Tomorrow's day number is: 3"
"Tomorrow is: Tue Feb 03 2015 08:18:06 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```